# define the mean average in haskell

Tags: haskell

how do you define the mean using type `[Float]`, without using recursion? also giving the answer to two decimal places. I'm new to Haskell so any help would be really really appreciated. I.e. `mean :: [Float] -> Float`.

For `mean xs = sum xs / length xs`, I got the following:

```
 No instance for (Fractional Int)
   arising from a use of `/' at test.hs:8:10-27
 Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
 In the expression: sum xs / length xs
 In the definition of `mean': mean xs = sum xs / length xs
```

Comment: Hint: you would get a more descriptive error message if you added an explicit signature for `mean`, because right now Haskell assumes `xs :: [Int]`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at `/`:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

As you see the result of `/` is of the same type as the operands.

Now let's look at `length`:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

Oops! You're passing an integer to `/`. Since (disregarding 0) the set of integers is not closed under division, `/` is not overloaded for integers.

Therefore, you first have to convert the second operand to floating-point number:

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

---

As for giving the answer to two decimal places, I'd leave that to the code responsible for presenting the result to the user. That's not the responsibility of `mean`.

Comment: Also consider the `genericLength` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want two decimal points, without rounding, you could use `div` rather than `/` (you'll have to move the decimal point in the result...):

```
meanish xs = div (sum xs * 100) (length xs)
```